# Получить часть строки

Tags: python

Есть главная строка строка:

```
S1 = 'Hello my friend'
```

К ней в любое место могут быть добавлены символы или слова:

```
S2 = 'Hello Dima my friend and you'
```

Так же могут быть удаленны любые слова в любом месте:

```
S3 = 'Hello friend'
```

Как получить добавленные и удаленные слова относительно главной строки ???

Comment: Если могут быть только операции удаления символов с конца строки или добавления их в конец строки - regexp не нужны совершенно. Уточните в вопросе этот момент.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  не обязательно в начало и конец, может быть удалена любая часть строки в любом месте, как и добавлена, нужно получить удалённую и добавленную часть

Comment: IMHO, это в сторону расстояния Левинштейна смотреть надо, а не регэкспов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html):

```
In [205]: import difflib

In [206]: d = difflib.Differ()

In [214]: removed = ''.join([s.replace('- ', '') for s in d.compare(S1, S3) if s.startswith('-')])

In [215]: print(removed)
 my

In [216]: added = ''.join([s.replace('+ ', '') for s in d.compare(S1, S2) if s.startswith('+')])

In [217]: print(added)
 Dima and you
```

Подробнее:

```
In [218]: list(d.compare(S1, S2))
Out[218]:
['  H',
 '  e',
 '  l',
 '  l',
 '  o',
 '+  ',
 '+ D',
 '+ i',
 '+ m',
 '+ a',
 '   ',
 '  m',
 '  y',
 '   ',
 '  f',
 '  r',
 '  i',
 '  e',
 '  n',
 '  d',
 '+  ',
 '+ a',
 '+ n',
 '+ d',
 '+  ',
 '+ y',
 '+ o',
 '+ u']
```

Comment: Вопрос изменил изначально не правильно задал, в любых местах могут быть добавлены и удалены слова, не только в конце и начале.

Comment: спасибо сработало